# Neutral grounding resistor

Tags: transformer, grounding, neutral

How does neutral grounding resistor in power generation side, see and link up with grounding fault at the secondary side of a transformer?

Answer (score 0):

If you are galvanically separating the power infeed side from the consumer side by using a transformer, any earth/ground fault on the transformer secondary will have no effect on the neutral earthing/grounding resistor on the primary. In other words, the two circuits (primary infeed and secondary consumer) are isolated in terms of earth/ground fault currents.